# How to configure git to ignore the ELF file type?

Tags: git, gitignore, githooks

Ideally, I would like to add a specific filetype to the .gitignore file, not by looking on the extension but instead looking on the file type.

I could for example examine the return code from

```
file some/file | grep -q ELF
```

If the return code is zero I don't want to add the file to the commit. Is there a way to achieve this either by editing the .gitignore file or by writing some kind of a git hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `pre-commit` hook you can prevent adding such files, either failing the commit of even silently removing them from index (with `git rm --cached "$filename"`). You could also make it populate `.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude` with list of all such files so that they do not appear in git status anymore, but this is a bit dangerous - if you later change a file into a script which you would like to keep into history you should remember to remove it from ignored list.

PS: as comment suggested, adding the hook example. It should be executable file in `.git/hooks/pre-commit`. Note that it is an example only, and I did not test it thoroughly.

```
#!/bin/sh

# --porcelain prints filenames either plain, or quoted with
# double-quotes and all special symbols as backspash sequences.
# another option is to add also '-z' which uses NUL delimiters
# and no quoting but handling such format with shell is complicated
git status --porcelain | while read -r st qfile; do
    if test "$st" != "A"; then
        # the operation is not adding; let it pass
        continue
    fi
    case "$qfile" in
    *\\*) # for special symbol handling, probably shell is really not a reasonable choice
        printf "Unsupported filename: %s\n" "$qfile"
        exit 1;;
    *' "') # trailing spaces need special care in gitignore; do not worth efforts
        printf "Unsupported filename: %s\n" "$qfile"
        exit 1;;
    '"'*'"') # we excluded all quoting, what's left are spaces only, just bite them off
        qfile1="${qfile%\"}"
        file="${qfile1#\"}";;
    *) # simple case
        file="$qfile";;
    esac
    type=$(file -b -i "$file")
    # the value to compare to is what file from Debian wheezy prints for binaries,
    # I don't know how portable this value is
    if test "$type" = "application/x-executable; charset=binary"; then
        git rm --cached "$file"
        printf "/%s\n" "$file" >>.git/info/exclude
    fi
done
```

Comment: A short example of a pre-commit hook that performs the request posted in question, and the information about how to install it would improve the quality of this answer a lot (and bring it more up-votes ;-) )